# Elegant transformation of various rules to strings, {f[z_] -> y} becomes "f = @(z) y"

Tags: pattern-matching, formatting, string-manipulation

Assume that I have some function for transformation mathematica expressions to strings.  For simplicity, just assume it is an identity:

```
mytostring[e_] := ToString[e]; (* In reality, much more complicated... *)
```

What I want to take various permutations of variadic rules syntax and apply this function to create a string for the function.  e.g. assume my basic test is:

```
rulestostring[rule_????] := ???
testrules = {f[x,y] -> x, f[x_,y_] -> x, f[x,y] :> x, f[x_,y_] :> x};

(* Create a function rulestostring where all of these give the same output as a string:
==>    "f = @(x,y) x"
Where the f is actually generated from mytostring[f], x is from mytostring[x], etc.
*)
```

I need it to support variadic arguments and a few other things:

```
otherrules = {f[x_] -> x, f[x[bar]] -> x[bar]};
(* ==>   {"f = @(x) x", "f = @(x[bar]) x[bar]"
where in reality both x[bar] would be transformed by mytostring
*)
```

(you can probably guess that what I am doing is extending the http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/ package to generate matlab functions.  If anyone has an updated version of this package it would be appreciated)

Comment: What is your end goal? To just convert to MATLAB expressions or to actually be able to inter-operate between MATLAB and _Mathematica_?

Comment: I want to generate functions that can be used in matlab (copy-paste).

Comment: I read your question a second time after posting my answer.  I think I'm missing something regarding `mytostring`.  What is `mytostring` supposed to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ruleToString[(Rule | RuleDelayed)[h_[a__], rhs_]] :=
  ToString @ Row[{h, " = @(", Row[{a} /. Pattern -> (# &), ","], ") ", rhs}]
```

Test:

```
ruleToString /@ testrules // Union
```

> ```
> {"f = @(x,y) x"}
> ```

```
ruleToString /@ otherrules
```

> ```
> {"f = @(x) x", "f = @(x[bar]) x[bar]"}
> ```

---

Based on communication in comments I propose this as a more complete solution:

```
Options[ruleToString] = {Format -> mytostring};

ruleToString[(Rule | RuleDelayed)[h_[a__], rhs_], OptionsPattern[]] :=
  With[{fn = OptionValue[Format]},
    ToString@Row[{fn@h, " = @(", Row[fn /@ ({a} /. Pattern -> (# &)), ","], ") ", fn@rhs}]
  ]
```

You can then change the function that is used to convert elements by using `SetOptions`, or by providing the option `Format -> function` directly in `ruleToString`.

Comment: Thank you, this seems very close.  `mytostring` will actually be the ToMatlab function that walks the expression tree to generate a matlab expression from that package I referenced, I just wanted to set things up in a minimal way.  For now, lets set: `mytostring[e_] := "_" <> ToString[e];` just so we can see that a transform has been applied.

Comment: With that def of mytostring, when I change your function to be: `ruleToString[(Rule | RuleDelayed)[h_[a__], rhs_]] := 
  ToString@Row[{mytostring[h], " = @(", 
     Row[mytostring /@ {a} /. Pattern -> (# &), ","], ") ", 
     mytostring[rhs]}];`   it seems to do what I want?

Comment: @jlperla Yes, that should do it if I understand your requirement.  You may want to do the `Pattern` replacement before mapping `mytostring`, i.e.:  `Row[mytostring /@ ({a} /. Pattern -> (# &)), ","]` but it's hard to say without seeing the function proper.

Comment: @mr-wizard  Thanks, I believe that is preferable and completes my requirements.  Consider editing your answer if you think it is more complete.

Comment: Also, how do you copy/paste in the output from mathematica into SE? as you did above?

Comment: @jlperla I merely copied it with `Ctrl`+`c`.  What difficulty are you having?